# Can I Insert a Particular Value to Replace the First Non-NULL Value in Each Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

[image]
I have a table as like above. 
I would like to insert particular value, which is called I1,I2,I3,...,I10. for the first non-Null value. But the value I want to insert vary based on what duration the first non-Null value lies.

For Example, the first non-NULL value for ID1 is Duration 3, then I would like to insert "I3" into that particular cell. For ID 2, I would want to insert I2 into that cell,etc.

There result I expect would look like
[image]

I1,I2,I3,...,I10 are some industrial value I have at hand, they are numbers not characters.

Is there a way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: please add some DDL or text ,images are blocked in some domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple `UPDATE` using `CASE` expressions:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET
    Duration1 = CASE WHEN Duration1 IS NOT NULL THEN I1 ELSE Duration1 END
,   Duration2 = CASE WHEN Duration1 IS NULL AND Duration2 IS NOT NULL THEN I2 ELSE Duration2 END
,   Duration3 = CASE WHEN Duration1 IS NULL AND Duration2 IS NULL AND Duration3 IS NOT NULL THEN I3 ELSE Duration3 END
-- Continue in the same boring way
,   Duration10 = CASE WHEN Duration1 IS NULL AND Duration2 IS NULL AND Duration3 IS NULL AND Duration4 IS NULL AND Duration5 IS NULL AND Duration6 IS NULL AND Duration7 IS NULL AND Duration8 IS NULL AND Duration9 IS NULL AND Duration10 IS NOT NULL THEN I10 ELSE Duration10 END
```